# Where should I ask easy meta questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering why the chat here is not frequented very well. I'd like to do some chit-chat like asking simple questions to prevent common pitfalls and  all the easy first-timer things that don't belong to meta.

What should I do? Go to SO's chat and ask there?

Comment: There should be a chat for MSO, that might not be a bad option.  Or you could browse MSO itself.  We don't really have enough consistently active users to sustain chat well yet, I think.

Comment: or maybe we do but no one gets in because it's always empty :/